# Extract value between two characters with varying positions

Tags: sql, t-sql

NOTE:  I am using TSQL

I need to be able to extract data from the middle of a string.  Both the length of the data I need, and the length of the string will vary.

Here are examples of the complete string:

```
362 Any Rd - NewPc#:420010079274892700465647513335 - StopID:12345

362 Any Rd - NewPc#:4200644392748927004720180006426006 - StopID:12345

362 Any Rd - NewPc#:00006675214112593057 - StopID:12345

362 Random Rd - NewPc#:420063709274892700465647550149 - StopID:4567
```

I only need the following from the above strings:

```
420010079274892700465647513335

4200644392748927004720180006426006

00006675214112593057

420063709274892700465647550149
```

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.  I was able to figure this out.  May not be the most elegant solution, but here is what I did:  SUBSTRING((SUBSTRING(OER.Note,PATINDEX('%#:%',OER.Note)+2,60)),1,(CHARINDEX('StopID',OER.Note,-6) - CHARINDEX('#:',OER.Note,2) - 5))

Answer (score 0):

```
Select SUBSTRING( Note,CHARINDEX ('#:' , Note, 1 ) +2,
                     CHARINDEX ( ' - S' ,Note ,1 )-
       CHARINDEX ('#:' , Note, 1 ) -2 )        
    from OER
```

You use 2 functions for your table oer:
 1st is to find the location for ":"

```
CHARINDEX ('#:' , Note, 1 ) +2
```

The +2 is to get rid of the "#:"

You need to use this 2 times, once again for the " - S" To see how many characters you want to go.

```
 CHARINDEX ( ' - S' ,Note ,1 )
```

And the 2nd function is `Substring` to use part of your Note

link sql fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95ce8/7/0

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I may have done something wrong but I got the following error message:   Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Didn't work this time either.  I just got - as the result.  My table name is OER.Note.  This is what I used:   SUBSTRING ( OER.Note ,CHARINDEX ( ' - S' ,OER.Note ,1 ) ,CHARINDEX ( ' - S' ,OER.Note ,1 )   - CHARINDEX ( ' - S' ,OER.Note ,1 ) +2)

Comment: What is your column name?

Comment: Excuse me.  Table OER  Column Note

Comment: Added SQL Fiddle link. Verified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `substring` and `charindex`.

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/546ff/1)

```
select 
substring(somecolumn, charindex(':',somecolumn) + 1,
         len(somecolumn) -
         charindex('-', reverse(somecolumn)) - 1 - charindex(':',somecolumn))
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

An example is this: You have a string and the character $

**String** :

```
aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc
```

**Code**:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc',CHARINDEX('$','aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc')+1, CHARINDEX('$','aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc',CHARINDEX('$','aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc')+1) -CHARINDEX('$','aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc')-1) as My_String
```

**Output**:

```
bbbbb
```